# Queries locking up DB Server CPU

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, database-deadlocks

We are using MSSQL server 2008 and our application has sql queries which locks up the DB at Row and Page levels. It is been said that because of the locks the CPU hit is 100%. Is there a procedure or way to find out which instance of MSSQL server is consuming how much CPU, so that i can narrow down this issue further?

Comment: It is *extremely* unlikely that Locks, on their own, could cause your CPU problems.  Unless your application is very poorly written (and tries to implement its own DB spin-locking), excessive locking tends to have the opposite effect: it causes CPU to drop.  Consequently, it is much more likely that it is your CPU and Locking issues are both caused by something else.

Comment: In any event, use Task Manager, Perfmon or Process Explorer, to see which processes on your server are using the most CPU.  (SQL Server instances each run in their own single process).

Answer (score 1):

To check for the running queries on a SQL SERVER and their state and CPU time.

```
SELECT sqltext.TEXT,
req.session_id,
req.status,
req.command,
req.cpu_time,
req.total_elapsed_time,
cn.*
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions AS cn
ON req.session_id= cn.session_id
```

Run this on each instance and see if it helps in  troubleshooting